# Cannot call from() operator on Observable in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

I'm trying to learn RxJava2 for Android using kotlin and I'm following an [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-reactivex-on-android--cms-24387) good online tutorial. First I added this two lines the gradle.build file:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
```

The I tried to implement the Observable pattern with this code:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val observable = Observable.from(arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

    }
}
```

This is supposed to work easily, but I cannot call from() operator on the Observable (Unresolved reference: from). So basically I'am stuck before I even started. Does any one have any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: Have you synced gradle after adding the dependency?

Comment: Of course I did

Comment: It his case you can use operator .fromArray() or .just().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` was removed in RxJava2 because it had a lot of overloads which might make it not behave as you would expect. It has been split into specific methods like `fromArray` or `fromIterable`.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Besides `from*` methods there are also extension functions for lists/arrays in rx-kotlin, so you might call for example `listOf(...).toObservable()`